# How to specify a specific range of dates

Tags: 2010, list, date-time, validation, calculated-column-formula

I have a `List` that tracks certificates. I need to limit two of the input fields and I'm not sure how.

[image: List item]

I have a formula (`=[Expiration Date]>[Last updated]`) in place that prohibits an `Expiration Date` greater than the `Last Updated` field. Now I need to prohibit a date greater than Today's, from being put into the `Last Update` field.

Would I make this in the `Validation Settings` where I made the initial rule? Or somewhere else?

Comment: SharePoint is already going to tell you the last time this list item was updated, why do you need a custom field for that?

Comment: I have a calculation that goes off this column

Comment: You can also calculate off the built-in Modified field. You're creating additional work for yourself going your current route.

Answer (score 1):

You can add two field validations

1. Expiration Date you can use formula `=If([Expiration Date]>[Last updated],TRUE,FALSE)`
2. Last Updated you can use formula `=If([Last Updated]<[Today],TRUE,FALSE)`